# Split date into multiple date ranges in Hive or SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, hive, hiveql

I would like to convert the below dates into different date ranges, here emp belongs to Chennai location from 2019-07-25 to 2099-02-14, but in between, emp worked from DEL between 2020-02-15 and 2020-02-23.

[image]

So I would like to convert above dates into below date ranges

[image]

Comment: But which record should take priority

Comment: place code MAA is priority one

Answer (score 0):

I have tried below in SQL Server and it works:

**Test Setup**

```sql
CREATE TABLE Employee(EmployeeId INT, fromDate date, todate date, Placename VARCHAR(100), PlaceCode VARCHAR(100))

INSERT INTO Employee
VALUES(1111,'2019-07-25','2099-02-14','CHENNAI','MAA'),
(1111,'2020-02-15','2020-02-23','DELHI','DEL');
```

**Query to Execute**

```sql
;WITH CTE_Ranges AS
(
SELECT EmployeeId, fromdate, lag(fromdate,1) OVER(PARTITION BY EmployeeId ORDER BY fromdate) previousfromDate,todate
, lead(todate,1) OVER(PARTITION BY EmployeeId ORDER BY todate) nexttodate, placename, placecode from Employee
)
--Handle the Maximum and minimum dates
SELECT * FROM 
(
SELECT EmployeeId, fromdate, DATEADD(day,-1,lead(fromdate) over(partition by EmployeeId ORDER BY fromDate)) as todate, PlaceName, PlaceCode
FROM CTE_Ranges
UNION ALL
SELECT EmployeeId, DATEADD(day,1,lag(todate) over(partition by EmployeeId ORDER BY todate)) as fromdate, todate,PlaceName, PlaceCode
FROM CTE_Ranges) AS t
WHERE fromdate is not null and todate is not null
UNION ALL
--Now handle normal date ranges
SELECT EmployeeId, fromDate,todate, placename, placecode
from cte_ranges
WHERE previousfromdate is not null and nexttodate is not null
order by fromdate
```

**Resultset**

```
+------------+------------+------------+-----------+-----------+
| EmployeeId |  fromdate  |   todate   | PlaceName | PlaceCode |
+------------+------------+------------+-----------+-----------+
|       1111 | 2019-07-25 | 2020-02-14 | CHENNAI   | MAA       |
|       1111 | 2020-02-15 | 2020-02-23 | DELHI     | DEL       |
|       1111 | 2020-02-24 | 2099-02-14 | CHENNAI   | MAA       |
+------------+------------+------------+-----------+-----------+
```

Answer (score 0):

To handle multiple levels of nesting, you can unpivot the data and

```
with e as (
      -- unpivot the dates
      select employeeid, fromdate as dte,
             placename, placecode
      from t
      union all
      select employeeid, enddate, null, null
      from t
     ),
     e2 as (
     -- impute the intermediate placenames
     select e.*,
            max(placename) over (partition by employeeid, grp) as imputed_placename
     from (select e.*,
                  count(placename) over (partition by employeeid order by dte) as grp
           from e
          ) e
    )
select employeeid, fromdate,
       dateadd(day, -1, lead(fromdate) over (partition by employeeid order by dte)) as enddate,
       placename, placecode
from e1;
```